# How to print this SQL statement month after month if I want to get 5 years?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to print this query month after month for one year.

1. That is, the result would be 12 corresponding selects from January to December.

That is to say for a year instead of writing 12 SQL queries, which shows month by month in a single query.

2. If I need to take out for an interval of 5 years, for example from 2012 to 2016, as I would do to show 60 selects ..

That is, for 5 years, instead of writing 60 SQL queries, it shows the 60 months in a single query.
How would I do it?

The date data is `V_FECHA_ORI_TREN.date BETWEEN 20120101 AND 20121228`

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT hc_tren.cod_numtr 
                      ||hc_tren.fec_oritr), 
       dm_punto_regulacion.desc_pr 
FROM   hc_tren, 
       dm_punto_regulacion, 
       dm_tiempo V_FECHA_ORI_TREN, 
       hc_movimientos_tren 
WHERE  ( hc_tren.cod_numtr = hc_movimientos_tren.cod_numtr 
         AND hc_tren.fec_oritr = hc_movimientos_tren.fec_oritr ) 
       AND ( hc_tren.fec_oritr = V_FECHA_ORI_TREN.fecha ) 
       AND ( hc_movimientos_tren.cod_pr = dm_punto_regulacion.cod_pr ) 
       AND ( Nvl(hc_movimientos_tren.flag_pr, 'S') = 'S' ) 
       AND ( Nvl(hc_tren.flag_sin_movimientos, 0) = 0 ) 
       AND V_FECHA_ORI_TREN.fecha BETWEEN 20120101 AND 20121228 
GROUP  BY dm_punto_regulacion.desc_pr;
```

Comment: It looks like your dates are stored simply as 8-digit numbers.  (I wouldn't recommend that; dates should always be stored in the date data-type to make sure they are valid and to make all the date functions easier to use.)

Comment: If they are stored as numbers you can do integer division  (round(v_fecha_ori_tren.fecha / 100)) to get the year and month and group by that.

Comment: I think its just a matter of adding year_month in the select & group by conditions but can you elaborate your problem + show us what you want with a small data-set so we can assist.